# XSLT Filter List of nodes, by another list of nodes, and loop over

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a variable $all, containing a list of nodes (complex nodes,including multi-level subnodes).
I have a second $filtered variable containing filtered nodes from $all.

nodes of $filtered has to been copied without modifcation.
the rest of nodes has to been modified.

Both variables are working, and everything is fine with them.

Now i like to loop with for-each over all nodes from $all not contained in $filtered.

Sure, I could rewrite the filter-expresion for $filtered in negative-style, but i did not like to do so and like to prevent this.
I did not like to grap on any attribute or element to handle it, because the filter expression can change, and some conditions are generated. I have to filter nodes from $all by every whole node of $filtered, including all subnodes, attributes and elements (like a fingerprint).

I do not get this to work.

I tried for-each select[....]

```
<xsl:for-each select="...">

    $all != $filtered
    $all/node() != $filtered/node()
    $all[node() != $filtered/node()]
    $all[not($filtered)]
    ... and some other
```

Can anyone point me the failure.

That must be possible somehow, but I guess I just can't see the forest for the trees.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you should be able to do...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="$all except $filtered">
```